# Send Ajax post value inside PHP Class

Tags: php, ajax, class, post

I'm trying to send a POST value inside a PHP class by Ajax, to change my SQL query.

**PHP Page**

```
 //Link page with Classes
 require_once('mPortfolio.php');
 $mPortfolio  = new Portfolio();
 $all         = $mPortfolio->getAll();

 //Echo sql results here

 //AJAX to send filter value to PHP with Classes
 $('#filters a').on('click', function(e){
        var filter = $(this).data('filter');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'models/mPortfolio.php',
            data: {filter: filter},
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```

**PHP Classes mPortfolio.php**

```
echo $_POST['filter']; //This works !

require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/models/db/db.php';

class Portfolio{

    private $_db;

    public function Portfolio()
    {
        $this->_db = new db();
        $this->_db->SQLRequest("SET NAMES utf8");
    }

    public function getAll()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['filter'])) :
            $query = "SELECT * FROM portfolio WHERE category='".$_POST['filter']."' AND online = 1 ORDER BY category,pos ASC";
        else :
            $query = "SELECT * FROM portfolio WHERE online = 1 ORDER BY category,pos ASC";
        endif;
        return $this->_db->SQLRequest($query);
    }

}
```

The mPortfolio.php page can actually read the $_POST['filter'] outside the Class, but the public function getAll() cannot.

Can you help me please make it work.
Thanks

Comment: You need to instanticate the object and call the method. A class definition on itself does nothing.

Comment: You are not creating an instance of that class in your code, so how do you expect the method to be executed …?

Comment: **SQL INJECTION**. Please escape `$_POST['filter']` before putting it in your query

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere, you must be creating an object of Portfolio class, and calling getAll(). From there, pass the $_POST['filter'] to getAll like

```
 $portfolioObj = new Portfolio();
 $portfolioObj->getAll($_POST['filter']);
```

The below 2 lines must be inside another PHP, which will include the mPortfolio.php

Answer (score 0):

Add following code:

```
$portfolio = new Portfolio();
$returnData = $portfolio->getAll();
echo $returnData;
```

below the class declaration.

This is because of class and functions cann't call directly. You need to call them for class you need to create the instance and then call the function inside the class. Without calling the class or function you cann't execute them.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 $('#filters a').on('click', function(e){
            var filter = $(this).data('filter');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'models/mPortfolio.php/getAll/filter/$_POST['filter']',
                data: {filter: filter},
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
         });
```

and get value in getAll function

```
OR 

$filter = $_POST['filter'];
$portfolio = new Portfolio();
$return = $portfolio->getAll($filter);
echo $return;
```